# String value for zlib output handler in php.ini

Tags: php, zlib, php-ini

Does Anyone know what kind of string I should use in `zlib.output_handler`? php.net manual doesn't help much about this.

Any further explanation on it would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I set `zlib.output_compression_level` to `On` so as [php.net states](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression) `output_handler` must be empty, while as you know the default value of `output_handler` is NULL and some of us are using default value of php.ini and fine with it, does it mean it's safe using `zlib.output_compression_level=On` with empty string `zlib.output_handler`?